# Showing div depending on option field value

Tags: jquery, html-select, show-hide

I have an option field dropdown with multiple options, what I am trying to do is once one of these sizes is selected then show a separate div regarding the size they have picked. The same div is shown no matter what size is selected. I have tried using the .change function in jQuery however when the page is reloaded and an option is still selected there is no change so the relative div is then hidden again, what is the best practice for this? I have thought about using .val() to show when one of the sizes has been selected?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<select id="pa_rooflight-size" name="attribute_pa_rooflight-size">
<option value="" selected="selected">Choose an option…</option>
<option value="3000mm-x-1200mm" class="attached enabled" selected="selected">3000mm x 1200mm</option><option value="750mm-x-750mm" class="attached enabled" selected="selected">750mm x 750mm</option><option value="900mm-x-900mm" class="attached enabled">900mm x 900mm</option><option value="1000mm-x-1000mm" class="attached enabled">1000mm x 1000mm</option><option value="1200mm-x-900mm" class="attached enabled">1200mm x 900mm</option><option value="1200mm-x-1200mm" class="attached enabled">1200mm x 1200mm</option><option value="1500mm-x-1000mm" class="attached enabled">1500mm x 1000mm</option><option value="1500mm-x-1500mm" class="attached enabled">1500mm x 1500mm</option><option value="1800mm-x-1000mm" class="attached enabled">1800mm x 1000mm</option><option value="2000mm-x-1000mm" class="attached enabled">2000mm x 1000mm</option><option value="3000mm-x-1000mm" class="attached enabled">3000mm x 1000mm</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#pa_rooflight-size').change(function(){  
     $('.flushglaze-panel').show(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: If I understood your question you can try triggering the change event on document ready `$('#pa_rooflight-size').change()`

Comment: I think you need to explain your problem again. Obviously you have multiple divs? Why don't you add all your html?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pa_rooflight-size").change(function() {
    $(".showPickedVal").show().html($(this).val());
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".showPickedVal").fadeOut('fast');
    }, 1000);
  });
})
```

The setTimout part is optional - don't know if you need it - it fades the
div out after 1 second.

Here is a working Plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/mzIGnMXp0ZTMJdXSmfaZ

> Edit:

After reading your question again, I understand that you want to show the selectbox's value initially. This is how you can do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#pa_rooflight-size").change(function() {
    $(".showPickedVal").show().html($(this).val());
  });
  $(".showPickedVal").show().html($("#pa_rooflight-size").val());
})
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/FHvpzAlPHfqsQZU3khR1?p=preview

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your response. I can see what you are doing with the .showPickedVal however I am not intending to display the size that the user has picked, only to show the .flushglaze-panel div which contains a diagram once they have selected a size.